# OnClick listener always shows same v.getId()

Tags: android, mvvm, onclicklistener

I am working on a simple login form with 4 kinds of users. The onclicklisteners view parameter always shows the same v.getId() value which was clicked first time. Eg if the student view is clicked,the  id value if updated but if i click the admin layout, the id still stays same as student.This happens with all the 4 sections.
Listener:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        loginActivityBinding.etPassword.setText("");
        loginActivityBinding.etUsername.setText("");
        loginActivityBinding.etPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener((v1, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!Utils.isValidPassword(loginActivityBinding.etPassword.toString())) {
                showToast("Please enter a valid password");
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Login", (dialog, which) -> {

            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(loginActivityBinding.etUsername.getText().toString(), loginActivityBinding.etPassword.getText().toString())) {
                showToast("Error .Please fill all fields");
            } else {
                Timber.d(String.valueOf(v.getId()));
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.ll_Admin:
                        mainLoginViewModel.login(loginActivityBinding.etUsername.getText().toString(), loginActivityBinding.etPassword.getText().toString(), 1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.ll_faculty:
                        mainLoginViewModel.login(loginActivityBinding.etUsername.getText().toString(), loginActivityBinding.etPassword.getText().toString(), 2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.ll_student:
                        mainLoginViewModel.login(loginActivityBinding.etUsername.getText().toString(), loginActivityBinding.etPassword.getText().toString(), 3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.counsellorlayout:
                        mainLoginViewModel.login(loginActivityBinding.etUsername.getText().toString(), loginActivityBinding.etPassword.getText().toString(), 4);
                        break;

                }
            }

        });
}
```

The flag value passed to the viewmodel stays the same after the first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating seperate click listeners using the setOnClickListener approach. bad approach surely but couldnt see any other way out.